# C++ Calling a function inside a function

Tags: c++, function, console-application

I try to call a function in `secim()` because I want to shorten this function, but it gives a c3861 error. I try a lot of things, but every time it gives a different error. I thought it would be best to share the function without splitting it, because I don't know which way is true. I am new to programming, I think it's an easy problem, but I can't solve it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fact(int n) { // function to calculate factorial of a number
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}


int npr(int n, int r) { // finding permutation
    int pnr = fact(n) / fact(n - r);
    return pnr;
}

int combin(int n, int r)
{
    int f1, f2, f3, y;
    f1 = fact(n);
    f2 = fact(r);
    f3 = fact(n - r);
    y = f1 / (f2 * f3);
    return y;
}

int secimm2(int s, int n, int r)
{
    int ss;
    cout << "yeniden denemek ister misiniz 1-evet 2-hayir" << endl;
    cin >> ss;
    if (ss == 1) {
        return secim();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int secim()
{
    int s, n, r;
    
    cout << "islem seciniz\n1-faktoriyel\n2-perm\n3-kombinasyon\n";
    cin >> s;
    if (s == 1) {
        cout << "1 adet sayi girin\ " << endl;
        cin >> n;
        cout << fact(n) << endl;
        return secimm2(s,n,r);
    }
    else if (s == 2) {
        cout << "2 adet sayi girin\n ";
        cin >> n;
        cin >> r;
        cout << npr(n, r) << endl;
        return secimm2(s, n, r);
    }
    else if (s == 3) {
        cout << "2 adet sayi girin\n ";
        cin >> n;
        cin >> r;
        cout << combin(n, r) << endl;
        return secimm2(s, n, r);
    }
    else {
        cout << "hatali giris tekrar dene\n" << endl;
        return secimm2(s, n, r);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int s;
    cout << "islem seciniz\n1-faktoriyel\n2-perm\n3-kombinasyon\n";
    cin >> s;
    cout << secim();
}
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: recursion without a termination condition will undoubtedly cause stack overflow.

Comment: secim identifier not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilator reads your code from top to bottom and will complain if it sees a function that isn't defined.

For example:

```cpp
void foo() {
    bar();    // Error: What is bar()? Not declared yet.
}

void bar() {
    foo();    // OK: foo was declared and defined above.
}
```

The solution is to declare the function causing the issue before calling it:

```cpp
void bar();   // Tells that a method void bar() exists. But doesn't define it yet.

void foo() {
    bar();    // OK: we know what bar() is: a call to the void bar() function.
}

void bar() {  // Bar is now defined. Signature must follow declaration.
    foo();    // OK: foo was declared and defined above.
}
```

With your code, it gives the following fix:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int secim(); // Declares the secim function, but doesn't define it.

int fact(int n) { // function to calculate factorial of a number
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}


int npr(int n, int r) { // finding permutation
    int pnr = fact(n) / fact(n - r);
    return pnr;
}

int combin(int n, int r)
{
    int f1, f2, f3, y;
    f1 = fact(n);
    f2 = fact(r);
    f3 = fact(n - r);
    y = f1 / (f2 * f3);
    return y;
}

int secimm2(int s, int n, int r)
{
    int ss;
    cout << "yeniden denemek ister misiniz 1-evet 2-hayir" << endl;
    cin >> ss;
    if (ss == 1) {
        return secim();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int secim()
{
    int s, n, r;
    
    cout << "islem seciniz\n1-faktoriyel\n2-perm\n3-kombinasyon\n";
    cin >> s;
    if (s == 1) {
        cout << "1 adet sayi girin\ " << endl;
        cin >> n;
        cout << fact(n) << endl;
        return secimm2(s,n,r);
    }
    else if (s == 2) {
        cout << "2 adet sayi girin\n ";
        cin >> n;
        cin >> r;
        cout << npr(n, r) << endl;
        return secimm2(s, n, r);
    }
    else if (s == 3) {
        cout << "2 adet sayi girin\n ";
        cin >> n;
        cin >> r;
        cout << combin(n, r) << endl;
        return secimm2(s, n, r);
    }
    else {
        cout << "hatali giris tekrar dene\n" << endl;
        return secimm2(s, n, r);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int s;
    cout << "islem seciniz\n1-faktoriyel\n2-perm\n3-kombinasyon\n";
    cin >> s;
    cout << secim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Error C3861](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3861?view=msvc-170) is "identifier not found". The problem is that `secimm2()` is trying to call `secim()` before `secim()` has been declared, so the compiler doesn't know what `secim()` is.

If you move the implementation of `secim()` above `secimm2()`, you would get a similar error about `secim()` trying to call `secimm2()` before `secimm2()` has been declared.

So, to solve this, you need to use a **forward declaration**, eg:

```
int secim(); // <-- add this

int secimm2(int s, int n, int r)
{
    ...
    return secim(); // <-- now you can call it!
    ...
}

int secim()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue (after you edited your question) is that the identifier `secim` has not yet been declared when it is first encountered (in the function `secimm2`). The normal way to get around this type of issue is by declaring function prototypes.

However, that's not appropriate here. You are using recursion to control what's actually a basic looping construct. Change your "continue" function as follows:

```
int secimm2()
{
    int ss;
    cout << "yeniden denemek ister misiniz 1-evet 2-hayir" << endl;
    return (cin >> ss && ss == 1) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

That will return 0 unless a value of 1 is successfully read.

Then in your main, you can just loop until `secim` returns zero:

```
int main() 
{
   while (secim() != 0);
}
```

Comment: "*Change your continue function as follows*" - Funny, this is *exactly* what I told the OP to do in their [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255733/c-does-not-start-over-when-main-function-is-called#comment131099606_74255733) before they deleted it.